# Failed to invoke JSON array for displaying location on maps

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, google-maps

I tried to displaying some markers from mySQL on my map using JSON and every time I open my app it crashes before even displaying a map.

route_activity.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.Menu;

public class route_activity extends FragmentActivity {
    private GoogleMap               map;
    private JSONHelper              json;
    private ProgressDialog          pDialog;

    private ArrayList<route_list>   listHalte;
    private final String            URL_API = "http://nfcworld.web.id/wibisono/retrieve.php";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_route);
        json = new JSONHelper();

        new AsynTaskMain().execute();

        setupMapIfNeeded();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(){

        super.onPause();
        if(pDialog != null)
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }

    private void setupMapIfNeeded()
    {
        if (map == null)
        {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            map = supportMapFragment.getMap();

            if (map != null)
            {
                setupMap();
            }
        }

    }

    private void setupMap()
    {
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        moveToMyLocation();
    }

    private void moveToMyLocation()
    {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));
        if (location != null)
        {
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 17));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.support_map, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
//line 102
        int resCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
        if (resCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
        {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resCode, this, 1);
        }
    }

    private class AsynTaskMain extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            pDialog.dismiss();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {

                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    for (int i = 0; i < listHalte.size(); i++)
                    {
                        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(new LatLng(listHalte.get(i).getLat(), listHalte.get(i).getLng()))
                                .title(listHalte.get(i).getNama()));

                    }
                }
            });

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(route_activity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading....");
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        } //line 147

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            JSONObject jObject = json.getJSONFromURL(URL_API);
            listHalte = json.gethalteAll(jObject);
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

JSONHelper.java

```
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
/**
 * Created by wibisono on 10/19/2016.
 */

public class JSONHelper {

    private InputStream     is              = null;
    private JSONObject      jsonObject      = null;
    private String          json            = "";

    private final String    TAG_HALTE       = "halte";
    private final String    TAG_ID          = "id";
    private final String    TAG_NAMA        = "nama";
    private final String    TAG_LAT         = "lat";
    private final String    TAG_LNG         = "lng";

    public JSONObject getJSONFromURL(String url)
    {
        try
        {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

        try
        {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);

        } catch (JSONException e)
        {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

        return jsonObject;
    }

    public ArrayList<route_list> gethalteAll(JSONObject jobj)
    {
        ArrayList<route_list> listhalte = new ArrayList<route_list>();

        try
        {
            JSONArray arrayhalte = jobj.getJSONArray(TAG_HALTE); //line 99

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayhalte.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject jobject = arrayhalte.getJSONObject(i);

                Log.d("log", "muter ke " + i);
                listhalte.add(new route_list(jobject.getInt(TAG_ID), jobject.getString(TAG_NAMA), jobject
                        .getDouble(TAG_LAT), jobject.getDouble(TAG_LNG)));

            }
        } catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return listhalte;
    }
}
```

route_list.java

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
/**
 * Created by wibisono on 10/8/2016.
 */
public class route_list {
    private int id;
    private String  nama;
    private double  lat;
    private double  lng;

    public route_list()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public route_list(int id, String nama, double lat, double lng)
    {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.nama = nama;
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lng = lng;
    }

    public String getNama()
    {
        return nama;
    }

    public void setNama(String nama)
    {
        this.nama = nama;
    }

    public double getLat()
    {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(double lat)
    {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public double getLng()
    {
        return lng;
    }

    public void setLng(double lng)
    {
        this.lng = lng;
    }

}
```

LogCat

```
11-22 23:30:57.355 15576-15767/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                   Process: com.example.wibisono.tryhard_1, PID: 15576
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.json.JSONArray org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                       at com.example.wibisono.tryhard_1.JSONHelper.gethalteAll(JSONHelper.java:99)
                                                       at com.example.wibisono.tryhard_1.route_activity$AsynTaskMain.doInBackground(route_activity.java:147)
                                                       at com.example.wibisono.tryhard_1.route_activity$AsynTaskMain.doInBackground(route_activity.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

map_route.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".route_activity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

retrieve.php

```
<?php 

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){

    define('HOST','localhost');
    define('USER','my_username');
    define('PASS','my_password');
    define('DB','my_database');
    $konek = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

$query = "SELECT * FROM halte";
$sql = mysqli_query($konek,$query);

$response = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
        array_push($response,array(
        "id" => $row['id'];
        "nama" => $row['nama'];
        "lat" => $row['lat'];   
        "lng" => $row['lng'];   
        ));
        }

    echo json_encode(array('halte'=>$response));
    mysqli_close($konek);

}
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.json.JSONArray org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Use breakpoints to determine what is wrong, but looks like the json object is not initalized when calling it in doInBackground

You need to initalize:     private JSONHelper  json;
Something like : private JSONHelper json = new JSONHelper();

Comment: @Nyranith I tried and still got the same error,any other possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the error was a typo on my `retrieve.php`, I typed `mysql_query` instead of `mysqli_query`
the map already showing up but the markers haven't (but it's okay though). Thanks for the advices :)